# How to install cocoapods package without cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want install this(https://cocoapods.org/pods/YandexMapKit) package into my project. But I use Carthage. How I can do this manually?

Comment: I'm afraid that the installation of pods is going to require pods. Or use GitHub maybe - but it will be a static framework https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-ios

Comment: You might have to do it yourself. Download the .zip, and make a Carthage around it.

Comment: @stevenpcurtis its old(not supported) version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/3/4/YandexMapKit/3.3.1/YandexMapKit.podspec.json:

```
  "source": {
    "http": "https://maps-ios-pods-public.s3.yandex.net/YandexMapKit-3.3.1.framework.zip",
    "sha1": "6657a666992abfffcc1f7c56f2d9cca9daf5bd33"
  },
```

and its YandexRuntime dependency from https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/5/7/2/YandexRuntime/3.2.0/YandexRuntime.podspec.json:

```
  "source": {
    "http": "https://maps-ios-pods-public.s3.yandex.net/YandexRuntime-3.2.0.framework.zip",
    "sha1": "b43adea5ed437b7c8f42af480447ba594c8330dd"
  },
```

Comment: How can I work with this package? I add it to project and Xcode shows me the methods, but the app crashes when I call something from it.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above you can clone the repo and build the framework yourself and drag it into your project, since Carthage doesn't seem to be supported.

If you want to be able to update the framework you can add the git repository as a git submodule in your project and have the framework as a target in your project. In your build phases your target should have the framework as a target dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed manual how to achieve this:

https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/issues/76

You can even check the demo project with YandexMapKit installed via Carthage:

https://github.com/ARGAMX/YandexMapKit-iOS-Carthage-Demo